# How to find out which player has closest bid in Price is Right game java?

Tags: java, loops, math

My Price Is Right program is still incomplete as I need to find out who my winner is each time.

The game's winner must have the highest bid that is most closest to the object's value, but cannot be more than the object's value.

How can I add the winner into my program?
Here is my code so far:

```
public class PriceisRight
{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    new PriceisRight();
  }

  public PriceisRight()
  {

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Price is Right!\n");

    String name1 = IBIO.inputString("Name of contestant #1: ");
    String name2 = IBIO.inputString("Name of contestant #2: ");
    String name3 = IBIO.inputString("Name of contestant #3: ");
    String name4 = IBIO.inputString("Name of contestant #4: ");
    System.out.println("");

  char again = 'y';
  while (again == 'Y' || again == 'y')
   {
    String THING = item ();
    System.out.println("The item to bid on is a "+ THING +".");
    System.out.println("The contestant who is the closest without going");
    System.out.println("over wins. The maximum bid is $1000.\n");

    int bid1 = IBIO.inputInt ( name1 +", what is your bid? ");
    int bid2 = IBIO.inputInt ( name2 +", what is your bid? ");
    int bid3 = IBIO.inputInt ( name3 +", what is your bid? ");
    int bid4 = IBIO.inputInt ( name4 +", what is your bid? ");

    again = IBIO.inputChar ("Play again? (y/n) ");
    System.out.println ("");
   }    
  }


  public String item ()
   {
    int num = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    int price = 0;
    String object = "";
     if (num == 1)
      {
        object = ("sofa");
        price = 987;
      } 

     else if (num == 2)
     {
        object = ("TV");
        price = 560;
     }

     else if(num == 3)
     {
        object = ("bed");
        price = 226;
      } 

     else if(num == 4)
      {
        object = ("table");
        price = 354;
      } 

     else
     {
        object = ("chair");
        price = 70;
      }
      return object;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to implement this yet? You have code that sets the price, but you don't use it. You'd need to return the price somehow, and then use it to compare to the bids.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. How do I do this?

Comment: Try something, anything, first. You need to get the price into your main method, but you're just returning a `String` with the object's name right now. Consider maybe creating a class/enum to represent your object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should have a class to hold relevant information to your players. Example;

```
class Player
{
    public String name;
    public int currentBid = 0;

    public Player(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void bid(int amount)
    {
        this.currentBid = amount;
    }
}
```

Now, create your instances.

```
player1 = new Player("Player 1");
player2 = new Player("Player 2");
player3 = new Player("Player 3");
```

Make your bids.

In your main class, try this.

```
public Player highestBidder()
{
    Player currentHighestBidder;

    //I am assuming you would logically keep track of the number of players, in an ArrayList in this case.
    for(int p = 0; p < players.size(); p++)
    {
        //Could easily combine this 'if' and the next one, but I prefer to keep my conditionals separated. It is probably a better practice to combine them using '||'
        if(currentHighestBidder == null)
        {
            currentHighestBidder = players.get(p);
        }

        if(players.get(p).currentBid > currentHighestBidder.currentBid)
        {
            currentHighestBidder = players.get(p);
        }
    }
    return currentHighestBidder;
}
```

I prefer to access non-vital fields directly, but you are more than welcome to add a method to fetch the `name` of your player and make the field `private`. Really just lazy typing on my part ;)

Comment: Java's an object-oriented language; too many students and beginners tend to think in terms of primitives all the time. Better to encapsulate like this.